# Variation and Taxonomy Navigation Get Friendly Url

Tags: variations, managed-navigation

I'm using Managed navigation (Taxonomy Navigation) feature of SharePoint Server 2013.
I've setup variation for 2 languages (en and fr).

Using the code below, I managed to get the relative url of the peer site:

```
  string url = Variations.GetPeerUrl(SPContext.Current.Web, currentUrl, label.Title);
```

For example when I'm in http://www.sample.com/en/Demo , using the code above I get /fr/Pages/Demo.aspx

What I wants is the managed navigation term or friendly url for it which is something like http://www.sample.com/fr/Demo

How can achieve that, what is the correct api that I should use here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agamand,

First from the complete URL you should get the List Item, using [SPWeb.GetListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlistitem.aspx)

See example here:
[get SPListItem reference from a url](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/cf42e8ae-45f2-4911-94a6-88b245115df4/get-splistitem-reference-from-a-url)

Than you can use following snippet to get Terms for the Page:

```
//retrieve the terms used for the navigation (this can be multiple terms)
IList<NavigationTerm> terms = TaxonomyNavigation.GetFriendlyUrlsForListItem(item, false);

string url = string.Empty;

//check if the pages has terms associated with it
if (terms.Count > 0) {
    //use the GetResolvedDisplayUrl to retrieve the page friendly urls
    url = terms[0].GetResolvedDisplayUrl(string.Empty);

    //Or you can use GetWebRelativeFriendlyUrl
} else {
    //if the page does not have any terms get the normal url
    url = item.File.Url;
}
```

I hope this helps